# how to migrate "repo init/sync" to "git" server?

Tags: git, gitlab, repo

I have a questions about "repo" to "git" migration including .repo dirs.

**< 1st Action >**
In order to prevent .git conflict, I delete all `.git` and `.repo` directories.
After I delete `.repo`, the original source does not compile successfully.

**< 2nd Action >**
So, I need to upload all `.repo` information to my new git server.
I `git add`, `git commit` and `git push` all source and `.repo` manually.
But the new git service source code does not compile successfully as well. recipe build error occurred.

**< need to solution >**
I received a project source using `repo init ~~~` and `repo sync`.
I have a Gitlab test server. Gitlab is using Git repo address as `git@<IP>:project/test.git`.

I would like to clone (mirror? duplicate?) repo, and sync all source and histories to my Gitlab server at the same time.
I would like to find solution, how do I replicate repo init/sync to git server?

Thank you.

Comment: You need to repo sync against google servers, then update the manifest file so that it uses your server. After that is done, you can do a push using the repo tool.

Comment: unfamiliar with repo, but the fact that your source code is not compiling has nothing to do with the versioning system used. Either [tag:git] or [tag:repo] are versioning systems, designed to help you track the changes you make to the code. They don't help you writing good or runnable code...

Comment: @DaemonPainter In some cases, the repository may fetch code from some remote repository during the compiling. So if the local repository is corrupted, it could fail.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `repo`, but if I recall correctly, a `repo` directory *is* a `git` repository.

You can `git push ssh://git@<IP>:project ...` without further modifications.

---

By the way : the `.git/` folder contains the database for your local `git` repo ; removing this folder means erasing all the history and all the branches of your repo. Don't do that :)

Answer (score 0):

The `repo` in `repo init` and `repo sync` is a launcher script. You can find what it is by `which repo`.

`repo init` creates `.repo` in the current folder, clones the repo-tool repository from the url to `.repo/repo` and checks out its branch. The url and the branch are specified by `REPO_URL` and `REPO_REV` in the launcher, or by options `--repo-url` and `--repo-branch`. The repo-tool repositoy contains the launcher and other sub-command scripts.

`repo init` accepts options `-u <url_to_manifest_repository>`, `-b <branch>` and `-m <manifest>`. `-u` specifies a repository which contains manifests. `-b` specifies the repository branch and `-m` specifies which manifest to use. `<branch>` defaults to `master` and `<manifest>` defaults to `default.xml`. The manifest repository is cloned to `.repo/manifest.git` and its working tree is `.repo/manifests`.

The manifest specified by `-m` instructs `repo sync` to fetch metadata of defined repositories. The metadata are stored in `.repo/project-objects` and `.repo/projects`. After metadata are fetched, the involved repositories' codes are checked out to paths defined in the manifest. The paths are also git repositories, but their `.git` folders are linked to `.repo/projects` and `.repo/project-objects`.

You want to push all repositories to Gitlab. First, create Gitlab repositories for all synced repositories. Second, create local orphan branches if you don't want to keep original history. Third, push local branches to Gitlab repositories.

The repo-tool has a sub-command `forall`. `repo forall` iterates all repositories and runs the commands specified by the option `-c <commands>` in each repository. You could also parse the manifest and use a loop to do the same job, which is more flexible. `-c` is convenient for a simple command. But for complicated commands, it's better to write a script.

Suppose there is a local repository whose name is `foo.git` and path is `foo`.

```
cd foo

# create an orphan branch if you don't want to keep the original history
git checkout --orphan <branch>
git commit

# create Gitlab repository with Gitlab API
# curl .....

# push the local revision to Gitlab repository
git push http://mygitlab.com/xxx/foo.git <branch>:refs/heads/<branch>
```

After all repositories are uploaded, you need to create a manifest to keep a record of Gitlab repositories so that you can use the repo-tool to download them from Gitlab. Based on the original manifest, you need to modify `<remote/>`, `<default/>`, and `<projects/>` according to the Gitlab repositories. After that, upload the manifest to your own manifest repository. For the manifest format details, you can find the doc in `.repo/repo/docs/manifest-format.txt`.